# Xpath with foreach

Tags: php, xpath

I'd like to get a ID from a node from my HTML? I have the major item, but I'd like to check if this item has a specific ID. How can I do this?

The HTML:

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="poly" coords="181,1283,83,1282,108,177,1124,174,1124,205,1124,213,1126,218,1141,221,1182,224,1204,224,1231,221,1253,218,1265,203,1266,174,2055,171,2055,1092,2002,1077,1935,1057,1920,1052,1904,1051,1901,1043,1893,1036,1874,1034,1861,1030,1829,1025,1802,1022,1785,1021,1765,1020,1741,1018,1723,1022,1720,1026,1714,1029,1713,1035,1715,1041,1713,1049,1616,1047,1509,1047,1436,1048,1417,1049,1386,1049,1318,1048,1304,1047,1300,1048,1288,1052,1278,1049,1247,1047,1177,1049,1135,1048,1069,1047,1047,1046,1000,1047,946,1047,902,1048,842,1048,814,1049,799,1049,778,1049,768,1051,763,1050,742,1048,698,1048,662,1048,573,1101,581,387,575,385,197,386,181,1283" href="#" />
  <area id="excludente" shape="rect" coords="952,491,1494,769" href="#" />
<area id="excludente" shape="poly" coords="654,599,663,580,669,577,731,578,736,579,739,588,738,599,738,677,734,682,729,684,667,685,662,679,659,668,653,600,653,598" href="#" />
  <area id="excludente" shape="poly" coords="1695,582,1697,579,1700,577,1709,576,1769,576,1771,578,1787,598,1786,605,1770,681,1764,685,1746,684,1705,683,1698,681,1696,675,1695,583" href="#" />
  <area shape="poly" coords="-1,84,2056,78,2055,0,0,0,0,83" href="#" />
</map>
```

My code:

```
        $DOM = new DOMDocument; 
            $DOM->loadHTML($conteudo['ambiente']->mapeamento);
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
            $tags = $xpath->query('//area/@shape');
            $total_local = 0;
            foreach ($tags as $linha => $tag) {
                $ctags = $xpath->query("//area/@id", $tag);
//How do I get the specific ID from area shape node?
            }
```

Comment: you need to post a piece of XML to we could see its structure, otherwise it is a wild guess at best

Comment: Sorry, now it's updated. Sometimes the id="excludente" appears, sometimes don't. I have to know that related with the shape tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a relative XPath.  You can either do this:

```
$tags = $xpath->query('//area/@shape');
$total_local = 0;
foreach ($tags as $linha => $tag) {
    // Context node is @shape
    $ctags = $xpath->query("../@id", $tag);
    $id = '';
    if(length($ctags) > 0) {
        $id = $ctags[0];
    }
}
```

Or this if you actually want to iterate through `area` elements and not `@shape` attributes:

```
$tags = $xpath->query('//area[@shape]');
$total_local = 0;
foreach ($tags as $linha => $tag) {
    // Context node is area
    $ctags = $xpath->query("@id", $tag);
    $id = '';
    if(length($ctags) > 0) {
        $id = $ctags[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument; 
$DOM->loadHTML($conteudo['ambiente']->mapeamento);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
$tags = $xpath->query("//area[@shape='whatever-shape-you-need-here']"); // $xpath->query("//area[@shape]") - if only need nodes that have shape attribute
$total_local = 0;
foreach ($tags as $linha => $tag) {
    $id = $tag.getAttribute("id"); // your needed id
}
```

Note, I have not done xpath for quite a while - really really rusty on it ;)