# Xpath inner foreach in PHP

Tags: php, xpath, foreach

I'm trying to use Xpath in PHP but I have a question about how to find a tag (ID) in the path and check whether or not it exists. With my code, I get just when it matches, but I have to just verify and get true or false if they exists or not for each one.

HTML for Xpath:

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="poly" id="normal"  coords="181,1283,83,1282,108,177,1124,174,1124,205,1124,213,1126,218,1141,221,1182,224,1204,224,1231,221,1253,218,1265,203,1266,174,2055,171,2055,1092,2002,1077,1935,1057,1920,1052,1904,1051,1901,1043,1893,1036,1874,1034,1861,1030,1829,1025,1802,1022,1785,1021,1765,1020,1741,1018,1723,1022,1720,1026,1714,1029,1713,1035,1715,1041,1713,1049,1616,1047,1509,1047,1436,1048,1417,1049,1386,1049,1318,1048,1304,1047,1300,1048,1288,1052,1278,1049,1247,1047,1177,1049,1135,1048,1069,1047,1047,1046,1000,1047,946,1047,902,1048,842,1048,814,1049,799,1049,778,1049,768,1051,763,1050,742,1048,698,1048,662,1048,573,1101,581,387,575,385,197,386,181,1283" href="#" />
  <area id="excludente" shape="rect" coords="952,491,1494,769" href="#" />
  <area id="excludente" shape="poly" coords="654,599,663,580,669,577,731,578,736,579,739,588,738,599,738,677,734,682,729,684,667,685,662,679,659,668,653,600,653,598" href="#" />
  <area shape="poly" coords="1695,582,1697,579,1700,577,1709,576,1769,576,1771,578,1787,598,1786,605,1770,681,1764,685,1746,684,1705,683,1698,681,1696,675,1695,583" href="#" />
  <area shape="poly" coords="-1,84,2056,78,2055,0,0,0,0,83" href="#" />
</map>
```

Code:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument; 
$DOM->loadHTML($conteudo['ambiente']->mapeamento);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
$tags = $xpath->query('//area/@shape');

foreach ($tags as $linha => $tag) {
    $ctags = $xpath->query("../@id", $tag);

    //Verify ecah one, not just the founded
    foreach ($ctags as $linha_item2 => $ctag) {
        echo $ctag->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should have finished asking it all here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215484/xpath-with-foreach/15215729

Answer (score 1):

Use `$tag->parentNode->hasAttribute('id')` on the shape `$tag` (which is actually an attribute), or do it in one xpath:

Area's with id, select the shape attribute:

```
//area[@id]/@shape
```

Area's without id, select the shape attribute:

```
//area[not(@id)]/@shape
```

Some examples (the `->parentNode` of an attribute is the actual `<area>` element it's in):

```
$tags = $xpath->query('//area/@shape');
foreach ($tags as $linha => $tag) {
    if($tag->parentNode->hasAttribute('id')){
          echo $tag->parentNode->getAttribute('id').PHP_EOL;
    } else {
          echo 'Oh no, I have no ID!'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
$ids =  $xpath->query('//area[@shape]/@id');
foreach($ids as $id){
        echo $id->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```